# How to use the continuous method when calculating difference between two dates?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to be able to calculate the number of years between two dates, for example the age of a person using their date of birth and today's date.

I've tried using the standard SQL DATE_DIFF function, however this only allows the discrete method rather than the continuous method that is required.

```
WITH TestData AS
(
  SELECT 'John Smith' AS Name,
          DATE '1976-08-12' AS DateOfBirth
)

SELECT Name, DateOfBirth, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DateOfBirth, YEAR) as Age
FROM
TestData
```

I'd want the output from this example to be 42, but what is currently being output is 43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH TestData AS (
  SELECT 'John Smith' AS Name, DATE '1976-08-12' AS DateOfBirth UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Joe the Plumber', '1976-07-12' 
)
SELECT Name, DateOfBirth, 
  IF(DATE_ADD(DateOfBirth, INTERVAL diff YEAR) > CURRENT_DATE(), diff - 1, diff) AS Age
FROM TestData, UNNEST([DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DateOfBirth, YEAR)]) diff
```

Or

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Age(dob DATE) AS ((
  SELECT diff - IF(DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL diff YEAR) > CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 0)
  FROM UNNEST([DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), dob, YEAR)]) diff
));
WITH TestData AS (
  SELECT 'John Smith' AS Name, DATE '1976-08-12' AS DateOfBirth UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Joe the Plumber', '1976-07-12' 
)
SELECT Name, DateOfBirth, Age(DateOfBirth) AS Age
FROM TestData
```

with result

```
Row Name            DateOfBirth     Age  
1   John Smith      1976-08-12      42   
2   Joe the Plumber 1976-07-12      43
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work - running it today returns 43 because it has now crossed the 12th monthly interval. This is the same issue as the yearly problem (discrete vs continuous method for calculating date differences).

Comment: Argh! I see now what you mean by continuous method. will update shortly

Answer (score 0):

too long but working

```
select
    date_diff(current_date, date'1976-08-12', year)
    - cast(date_sub(current_date, interval date_diff(current_date, date'1976-08-12', year) year) < date'1976-08-12' as int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems to be working as intended! :)
It's frustrating that there doesn't seem to be a simpler way to solve this though.

Comment: I think there is an easier way, but for now this is all I came up with `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: If for now this is the best answer, that solves your problem, you can also mark it as accepted)